# Как получить аннотации класса, переданного в качестве класса в дженерик

Tags: java, generics, рефлексия

Eсть generic класс

```
public class Test<T>{
  public T f(){ 
    //код
  }
}
```

Классы, передаваемые дженерику будут помеченны анотациями. Задача - добраться до анотаций клаccf T.

- T.class не получается
- (new T()).getClass не поучается.

Как взять класс (анотаци) от передаваемого в дженерик класса T?

Comment: Reflection API?

Comment: А как конкретно?

Comment: в текущем варианте никак из-за стирания типов, придётся явно передавать объект `Class<T>` в функцию `f()` или в конструктор `Test`

Comment: спасибо___________